# ASP.NET MVC redirect to 403/404 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages, custom-error-handling

I have the following web.config section:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Home/Error">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Home/Error404"/>
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="/Home/Error403"/>
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Home/Error"/>
</customErrors>
```

then I have the following code:

```
return HttpNotFound();
```

When I call this code I got the following page:

[image]

Why I don't see my special page?

Comment: have you tried hosting it on test environment

Comment: yes, I test on localhost

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure below points

1) All the custom error action having their own action methods like below.

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    public ViewResult Error404()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;  //you may want to set this to 200
        return View("NotFound");
    }
    public ViewResult Error403()
    {
        ------
    }
}
```

2) And confirm all the actions having their own views.